# Pixel size for different browsers

Tags: css, browser, pixel

Is the pixel size different for different browsers?

For example

```
<input type='button' class='button2' value='...' />

/*****CSS*****/
.button2{
     width:120px;
}
```

overflows the button value in Chrome but doesn't so in Safari and Firefox.
What am I doing is wrong?

Comment: it is visually same across all browsers under same resolution.

Comment: What overflows where? Can you provide a clearer example - a screenshot perhaps?

Comment: the button value doesn't completely fit in the specified width in Chrome but does so in Firefox and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Pixels *should* be the same. If you investigate, you may find that the different browsers have different default values for things like margins, padding, text size, font face, etc. That's probably what's tripping you up (though I would note that popping that code into my own browsers does not produce any overflow.)

Answer (score 0):

1. use [css-reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)
2. different browsers render elements differently. Look your button in IE, you will be surprised :)