# Why is there difference in paddings/margins/top/bot etc in different browsers?

Tags: html, css, browser, cross-browser

I've been developing for a long time and always noticed this problem, sometimes there is different in how margins and similar things look on different browsers, it is usually this annoying 1px difference, which sometimes makes big difference when you are going for pixel perfect layout. I tried researching it, but didn't find anything useful which would also include a solution.

Why is this happening? Is there a solution? I've been using selectors for mozilla firefox, but now there is difference in safari and chrome, both webkit. Just don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`reset.css`

Comment: May be a subpixel rendering problem, but the real solution is *don't* go for a "pixel perfect" layout, but rather a fluid one

Comment: @Doorknob am actually using it, yet still. I also notice slight colour difference sometimes.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @Sourabh http://freshbeer.lv/mg51/index.html Hover over volume controls, there is this 1px difference that is killing me. and Opera is completely mad.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Because it is not well standardised.

Comment: Ok, seems that you are asking about different behaviour of applied styles, not initial ones. Then [`Normalize.css`](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) won't help, but the answer to your question remains the same.

Comment: Read following linkes i think you will find your answer.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717179/pixel-size-for-different-browsers